# Use tertiary operator in jsx tag for attribute?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a bit of a weird question but so far I did not find this question being asked somewhere.

If I try to render a classname conditionally with jsx I'd do something like this:

```
<input 
{...input}
type={type}
className="form__input"
classname={boolean ? "boo" : null}
/>
```

With a boolean attribute like "disabled" this does not seem to work. E. g.:

```
<input 
{...input}
type={type}
className="form__input"
{disabled ? "disabled" : null}
/>
```

This seems logical since I don't want to insert a string as an jsx attribute. But Is there really no other way than rendering the entire jsx tag conditionally?

```
if (boolean) { <input disabled />} } else { <input /> }
```

Comment: Would not `<input disabled={disabled} />` works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` is not HTML attribute but JSX prop. They are intended to be used conveniently with JavaScript expressions.

`disabled` prop with no value is [the same as `disabled={true}`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#props-default-to-true), while `disabled={false}` prop will result in `disabled` attribute not being added.

Considering that `disabled` variable is boolean, it should be:

```
<input 
{...input}
type={type}
className="form__input"
disabled={disabled}
/>
```

Comment: that was a bit of slow thinking on my part! Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As Federkun indicated in the comments, you can just do:

```
<input 
{...input}
type={type}
className="form__input"
disabled={disabled}
/>
```

If the boolean is true, the attribute will be included as a bare attribute. If it is false the attribute will not be included.

You can see the discussion of enhancing JSX to support this behavior back in 2014 here:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/961